# Get same button to call different methods on different clicks

Tags: java, android

How can I get a button inside a switch case to call 2 different methods, on 2 different clicks?

Example: If I have a button:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){ 
                case R.id.keypad_submit:

                DoSomething1();
                DoSomething2();
                Break;
           }
    }
```

How can I get method `DoSomething2()` to run the second time I click the keypad_submit button, because at the moment it runs as soon as keypad_submit is clicked. So 1st click should just run `DoSomething1()` only and the click after that should run `DoSomething2()` only. (I should be able to repeat this click process multiple times)

Many thanks for any help

Comment: simplest way take a static integer and increment it on each case and condition it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

When you click button `boolean` true again you click `boolean` false.

```
 boolean flag = false;

switch(v.getId()){ 
        case R.id.keypad_submit:
        if(flag){
        DoSomething1();
        flag = false;
        }esle{
        flag = true;
        DoSomething2();

        }
        Break;
 }
}
```

Comment: flag value isnt being changed. will perform doSomething2() everytime

Comment: after calling DoSomething1() change flag value false. again calling dosomething2() change flag true simultaneously.

Comment: the `flag=false` and `flag=true` statements weren't there when i saw it. That's y posted that comment. :)

Comment: @Muraliganesan thanks for reply, I tried but it jus runs into DoSomething2() and thats it

Answer (score 0):

Keep a global count variable initialized to 1:
`count=0`
 Use the following code to perform different functions:

```
if(count==0) {
   doSomething1();
   count++;
}
else {
   count=0;
   doSomething2();
}
```

This should help you with your problem.